# Python -- Limits On Number of Imports?

Tags: python

I have 1000s of custom (compiled to '.so') modules that I'd like to use in `python` at the same time. Each such module is of size (`100 [KB]`) on average.

My question is, is there any limit on the number of imports in `python`? what are the consequences of many `imports`? (for example, will this require a lot of memory)?

Can I import 10,000 custom modules? 50,000 modules?

Comment: My good God.  I have no idea of the answer, but I'd love to know what drove you to need to ask the question.

Comment: How many imports are you using?  At what point have you started to notice something different?

Comment: excellent question! question like this make use think!

Comment: Sound like a job for Refactor Man.

Answer (score 10):

There's **no Python limit on number of imports** in a module. If there's a limit in any particular implementation, it's probably because of resource limits outside the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 9):

The amount of memory consumed by a single imported module is going to be at *least* as big as the size of the module on disk. The overhead is determined by both the OS itself (for loading a dynamic module) and Python's overhead in importing a module.

So if your module are on average 100kB in size, then importing 10000 of them will take up at *least* 1 GB of address space. Importing 50000 of them will run over 5 GB. You'd better be using an operating system with a 64-bit address space.

Answer (score 3):

CPython has no limit on the number of imports. However, each `.so` file will be opened using `dlopen()`, which is outside of Python's control -- as is the symbol table that would need to keep growing to collect information about your extension modules. Whether those have a practical limit is also outside of Python's purview. CPython itself merely takes up some memory per module you import, so as long as you have enough memory you should be fine.

Comment: thank you. Do you have an idea what is the overhead of every `.so`, when imported? is the overhead correlated to the size of the `.so` file on disk? or is it separate (smaller, I hope) to the size of the `.so` on disk?

Comment: any hints on how much memory is taken by `CPython` per every module imported?

Comment: The overhead in Python is a fixed amount per module, plus more overhead for what's actually *in* the module. It depends greatly on the Python version and how it was built and what the modules actually contain. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by full RAM. You need to free some RAM.
I have this experience with jupyter notebook that I cannot import new local functions.
After restarting the python kernel, it works!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33122430)