# Python -- Overhead of `.so` Imports?

Tags: python

I have 1000s of custom (compiled to '.so') modules that I'd like to use in `python` at the same time. Each such module is of size (`100 [KB]`) on average.

Does anyone know what is the overhead (on the OS -- assuming `python` is not handling this) of every `.so` import? meaning, is the overhead equal to the size of the `.so` file on disk? or is it a fixed, regardless of the size of the `.so` file?

I haven't yet gotten there, but would be curious to know what is the impact on the OS when one wants to import, say 10,000-50,000 custom modules at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python -- Limits On Number of Imports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012022/python-limits-on-number-of-imports)

Comment: @sdolan: it is not a duplicate; the former deals with the actual number of `.so` imports; this one deals with the overhead of the `.so` modules.

Comment: Why are you importing all of them at once? Why not import them before they are needed? Is this for python in general, or, it sounds like, you are concerned about a particular OS?

Answer (score 3):

There would be a large time overhead of importing that many shared libraries - the dynamic linker would spend a significant amount of time during the loading phase. The dynamic linker is really optimized for tens to hundreds of shared objects, not thousands to tens of thousands.

If at all possible, combine your shared code objects.

However, the size once loaded is likely somewhat smaller than the one disk size, depending on what other information is in the file (DWARF debug symbols, extra ELF sections not required, etc).

Comment: thank you. so better to have one huge `.so` file that unites say 1000s of `.so` modules together? will the overhead be the same if one imports say 10000 `.so` or if one imports one huge `.so` that is composed out of these 10000 individual `.so` files?

Comment: @user: There is extra overhead from having more .so files (more records for what is loaded and similar memory). There is also more time involved (the linker is starting up 1000s of times vs. one time), for mostly duplicate symbols (Python calls, OS calls, etc).

Comment: thank you. Does it help if one imports only part of a module's functionality instead of all of it? for example, instead of `import Y`, I will do `from Y import X1,X2,X3....` ; Will it help in anything / be more economical in terms of resources?